# How to populate textbox with value of gridview control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, textbox

With just a regular value you would write something like

```
  protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow email = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    txtbox.Text = email.Cells[5].Text;

}
```

However, I want to populate that textbox with a value that is a textbox control in the gridview. I have a list of rows and depending on which row I select that textbox will populate with that control value. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using datakeys for this. It's a lot easier and a lot more reliable than using the cell index:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Column1, Column2" ...>
```

Then, in the code-behind you can access the values like this:

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow email = GridView1.SelectedRow;
    txtbox.Text = (string)GridView1.DataKeys[email.RowIndex]["Column1"];    
}
```

Comment: would this apply to controls?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you referring to data keys?

Comment: Are you trying to populate the value from a control in the `GridViewRow`?

Comment: ah nvm. Yeah I think datakeys are the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code.

```
TextBox tb = GridView1.SelectedRow.FindControl("textboxId") as TextBox;
textbox.Text = tb.Text;
```

Comment: I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error. But I feel that it is really close.

Comment: This is because tb must be null. add If(tb != null) textbox.Text = tb.Text;

Comment: If you would have been using SelectedIndexChanging then the code will be TextBox tb = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex].FindControl("textboxId") as TextBox;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
GridView1.RowCommand += GridView1_RowCommand;
private void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument));
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];
            this.NameTextBox.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(row.Cells[1].Text);

        }

}
```

Comment: @Kamran-Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You can find a better code here on how to populate gridview with the text box values of your form.
http://sharepoint-2010-world.blogspot.in/2013/10/populating-grid-with-form-values.html

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers, to get more understanding how to **not** answer. Namely: "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question": **barely more than a link to an external site**